# Will my epson stylustx121 printer work in ubuntu?

Tags: installation

I installed Ubuntu in my PC just weeks ago.I printer used to work in windows 7 ultimate 32 bit version(which i was using). But now my windows 7 doesn't boot and I'm also not able to use my printer.
Model name: Epson stylus TX121
Should i install some other software? or what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am also using the same Printer **Epson Stylus TX121**. It works out of the box with Ubuntu. You have to download drivers from [here](http://avasys.jp/eng/linux_driver/). Those drivers are free to download and use. You need to download separate packages for Printer and scanners to work.

Visit this [Blog](http://www.howopensource.com/2012/08/linux-driver-for-epson-printers-and-scanners/) to **Get started**